# Recyclerview: expanding a textview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged, expandable

I have a textView inside a recyclerview currently that looks like this:

[image: textview]

The full text says: "This is the place where I would put the information about the food item. I want to truncate the line to only show 3 lines and then when I press on the caret, it will expand to the maximum amount of lines."

If I click on the caret (the little down arrow at the top), I want it to expand so that I can see all the lines.

In my recyclerview adapter, I have the following code:

```
    if (holder instanceof InfoViewHolder) {
        ((InfoViewHolder) holder).more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!expandedInfo) {
                    ((InfoViewHolder) holder).info.setMaxLines(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
                    expandedInfo = true;
                }
                ((InfoViewHolder) holder).info.setMaxLines(3);
                notifyItemChanged(position);
            }
        });
    }
```

I'm just manipulating the maxLines in the textView to try and expand the space it will take in the textView so that the view will adjust itself when I notifyItemChanged, however, this does not work and my information textview does not expand.

Can anyone tell me how I can get this to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this library was probably the easiest and the quickest way to solve this puzzle:

https://github.com/Manabu-GT/ExpandableTextView

Although, I would have like to have done it the old fashion way instead of importing a new library so if anyone else has any ideas on how to do this without a library, feel free to post your suggestions below.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it didn't work because `((InfoViewHolder) holder).info.setMaxLines(3);` is called no matter what.

So, inside the `OnClickListener`, it should be:

```
int maxLines = expandedInfo ? Integer.MAX_VALUE : 3;
((InfoViewHolder) holder).info.setMaxLines(maxLines);
notifyItemChanged(position);
```

Also, about the [`ExpandableTextView`](https://github.com/Manabu-GT/ExpandableTextView) library, currently it doesn't work in `RecyclerView`. See my [comments on the issue](https://github.com/Manabu-GT/ExpandableTextView/issues/14#issuecomment-192551941).